# Setting up Firebase push notifications for custom Matrix client

Tags: flutter, matrix, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've found the documentation for push gateways:

- https://spec.matrix.org/v1.5/push-gateway-api/

and a couple repos implementing it;

- https://gitlab.com/famedly/company/backend/services/famedly-push-gateway/-/tree/master/.
- https://github.com/matrix-org/sygnal

Setting up a push gateway seems to be the missing link for us. However, before we get into hosting our own server, I'm wondering - Is it possible to create a custom Matrix client with push notifications **without** hosting a push gateway?

I have tried going through the synaps and didn’t see any link for that.